# jQuery.hide() hides, but .show() doesn't show them back

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I have a `div#content` that has 3 `div`s inside (`product-a-content`, `product-b-content` and `product-c-content`) and each one has some children elements as well.
At any time, only one of the 3 `div`s should be visible. The code to change the active `div` is this:

```
    $('.mainmenuitem').click(function(){
        $('#content div').hide();
        $('#content div#' + this.id + '-content').show();
    });
```

And the markup:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <div id="product-a" class="mainmenuitem"></div>
    <div id="product-b" class="mainmenuitem"></div>
    <div id="product-c" class="mainmenuitem"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="box">
        <div id="product-a-content"><?php echo $product_a_info; ?></div>
        <div id="product-b-content"><?php echo $product_b_info; ?></div>
        <div id="product-c-content"><?php echo $product_c_info; ?></div>
</div>
```

They become `hide`, but not active, cannot be active then. (I'm even sure that the right `id` is returned to be visible again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#content div')` hides all `div` inside `#content`, even the indirect children of `#content` element, when you display it back, you are displaying only the direct child div.

When you hide the elements, you need to hide only the direct divs

Try

```
$('.mainmenuitem').click(function(){
    $('#content > div').hide();
    $('#' + this.id + '-content').show();
});
```

Comment: My god, you broke the fast reply record! YES, it has worked like a charm! But I should wait 10 more mins to accept!